# Phpmailer undefined method error

Tags: php

I am trying to send an email with an HTML form with phpmailer. I currently have the latest version in my project but an error is popping up.

**Code:**

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $name = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $email = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
    $adress = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "adress", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $date = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "date", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $timefrom = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "timefrom", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $timeto = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "timeto", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
    $payment = trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "payment", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));


    if ($name === "" || $email === "" || $adress === "" || $date === "" || $timefrom === "" || $timeto === "" || $payment === "" ) {
        echo "Please fill in all fields";
        exit;
    }

    require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    if (!$mail->ValidateAdress($email)) {
        echo "Invalid Email Adress";
        exit;
    }

    $email_body = "";
    $email_body .= "Name: " . $name . "\n";
    $email_body .= "Email: " . $email . "\n";
    $email_body .= "Adress: " . $adress . "\n";
    $email_body .= "Date: " . $date . "\n";
    $email_body .= "Time from: " . $timefrom . "\n";
    $email_body .= "Time to: " . $timeto . "\n";
    $email_body .= "Payment Method: " . $payment . "\n";


    // PHP MAILER CODE:
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('sebastian.vireal@gmail.com', 'Soreal main account');     // Add a recipient

    $mail->isHTML(false);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Soreal VR Contact Form' . $name;
    $mail->Body = $email_body;


    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        exit;
    }

    header("location:thankyou.php");

}

?>
```

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer::ValidateAdress() in /home/soreal/public_html/process.php on line 23
```

**The error is occurring on the line of the IF statement below:**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

    if (!$mail->ValidateAdress($email)) {
        echo "Invalid Email Adress";
        exit;
    }
```

I have tried changing from require to include. I have also tried including the PHPMailerAutoload.php file.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `validateAddress` Check the spelling

Comment: Typo questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Please check function spelling. If it is not working
then use

```
$valid = phpMailer::ValidateAddress($email_address);
```

Comment: just mark/flag the question as a typo; it's off-topic.

Comment: here: if (!$mail->ValidateAdress($email)) {
        echo "Invalid Email Adress";
        exit;
    }